# Mark required field's label based on assigned validator in Angular 2 form

Tags: css, forms, validation, angular

I have an Angular 2 form with lots of required fields. Those have `Validators.required` assigned. I want to add an asterisk to these fields' labels.

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
   <div class="form-group row">
     <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">First Name -> Add asterisk here</label>
     <div class="col-sm-9">
       <input formControlName="firstName" type="text" class="form-control">
     </div>
   </div>
...
```

I have googled and read the [docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html), but can't find an implementation for this use case.

I know I can add the required attribute manually and work from there, but I would prefer to avoid as this seems redundant with the validator assignment.

Comment: what the type of `Validators.required`? if it is a `boolean`, you could use `*ngIf` to do this.

Comment: Well, you can try something with `*ngIf="form.get('firstName').hasError('required')"`, but it'll only apply the asterisk when the field is blank. Since the field is filled, the method will return `false`.

Comment: so have you already found some good solution?

Comment: @PetrAdam: Nope I added the asterisks manually for now. Sorry for the delayed reaction though. And thanks a lot for your input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure, if its the best *ng2-style* solution, but what about this:

Let your `FormComponent` hold an array of required fields. In your template you can simply use something like:

```
<label for="firstName">
    FirstName <span *ngIf="isFieldRequired('firstName')"> *</span>
</label>
```

You can create separate component for Label with asterisk, if you don't want to repeat the code through your template, for example:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-label',
  template: `<label for="{{id}}">{{label}} <span *ngIf="isFieldRequired(id)"> *</span></label>`
})
export class MyLabelComponent {
  @Input() label: string;
  @Input() id: string;
  @Input() requires: [];
  constructor() { }

    isFieldRequired(id) {
      return this.requires.indexOf(id) !== -1; // check if the array contains the value
  }
}
```

In your `Form Component`, you just pass values to the my-label component, like:

```
<my-label [requires]="requiredFields" [label]="'Name'" [id]="'name'"></my-label>
```

Here is **working plunker** of this example: http://plnkr.co/edit/M66IFQGhhe82mNt3ekxw?p=preview
with the idea how to use the required definition together with more custom validators. See *app.component.ts*

Comment: I agree that this should work, but it looks like you're just moving the redundancy around instead of avoiding it. You now have to add every required field to `requiredFields`, right?

Comment: Correct, but that's actually the only place, where required fields are defined. just this array. Validators are then applied based on it.

Comment: OK, now I get it. I would suggest to scratch the idea with the extra component and to instead explain the addition of Validators.required in the answer. Would make it easier t understand without looking for it in the plunker. Still: much appreciated! Upvoted, but not accepted (yet) to encourage alternative ideas.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense, thx..I knew the solution is not perfect, so not accepting answer yet is also good. I would expect there is something you can pass a form control name, and get list of all validators related to that form control..that would solve it. But didn't find anything like it

Comment: Exactly. I learned a few things from looking at your solution and really appreciate your input. Let's see if other ideas come along over the weekend and if not, I'll accept yours.